# jQuery Ajax fails when accessing a resource (Django Tastypie)

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, rest, tastypie

I've created a simple resource that via GET outputs my json object. The URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/advert/?format=json` and works fine. Now when I try and access the resource using jQuery ajax method I get;

[image]

[image]

This is my JavaScript;

```
$.ajax({
        url : 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/advert/',
        dataType : 'json',
        type : 'GET',
        data : { format: 'json' },
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

What is causing this and more importantly how do I correct it? The same error happens when I try and implement Django Piston with a simple resource, so I am guessing this is problem is more to do with the actual AJAX request?

EDIT.

I've adjusted the jQuery ajax call slightly and included the request content.

Comment: Shouldn't you use the data option to include GET parameters (eg format) ?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the JS code to now use the data parameter. Unfortunately it still fails.

Answer (score 4):

After a number of head scratching moments and trying to emulate the error using curl, I finally found the source of the problem. I am using Google Chrome browser with the extension Adblock Plus (Adblock Plus (Beta) 1.2). After disabling this extension, the ajax request works fine! I'm not sure how exactly ABP was affecting it but it was most definitely the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your ajax code for a tastypie API of my own that I know is working.

I also get a "red" result line for an OPTIONS request the jQuery ajax command sends initially. If I look at the response for that request I see it actually an OK 200.

It seems the ajax call makes the OPTIONS request, gets a 200 response status and then cancels the transfer since it already has everything it needs in the "Allow" response header.

In your case it looks like its actually failing for some reason (or maybe the browser just describes it differently?).

Can you add the response headers you get?

(I would share my screenshots, but I'm still working up my rep :-/)

Comment: Hi there, I've updated the original post with additional screenshots and amended the ajax call slightly. It still fails (although slightly differently - request method is now GET instead of OPTIONS). There is also no response header information so I don't think the ajax call actually get's there?